# no route for route that is shown in 'rake routes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an extra route in my rails application to my nested resources like this.

```
 resources :questions do 
    resources :answers do 

       match "/bestanswer", :to => "answers#bestanswer", :via => :post

      end
  end
```

Running 'rake routes' shows the following path

```
question_answer_bestanswer POST   /questions/:question_id/answers/:answer_id/bestanswer(.:format) answers#bestanswer
```

I tried to use the path in a form (which is repeated many times for each answer) like this

```
<%= form_tag question_answer_bestanswer_path, method: :post do%>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :answer_id, answer.id %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :question_id, answer.question.id %>
   <%= submit_tag "Accept this answer as the best answer", :class => 'btn ' %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I go to the page where this form is displayed, I get this error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"answers", :action=>"bestanswer"}
```

Can you explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: You didn't provide a question or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the route parameters, your form should be:

```
<%= form_tag question_answer_bestanswer_path( answer.question, answer ), method: :post do%>
   <%= submit_tag "Accept this answer as the best answer", :class => 'btn ' %>
<% end %>
```

And the `hidden_field_tag`'s are not necessary.